# Is there a working example of the bootstrap popover selector

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

In the documentation for the Bootstrap Popover there is a link to an [informative example](https://jsbin.com/zopod/1/edit) with the following code:

```
function usingSelectorOption() {
  return $('#use-selector').is(':checked');
}

function updateCodeView() {
  $('#with-selector-code').toggle(usingSelectorOption());
  $('#without-selector-code').toggle(!usingSelectorOption());
}

$(function() {
  // Update code view when checkbox is toggled
  updateCodeView();
  $('#use-selector').click(function() {
    updateCodeView();
  });


  var startedDemo = false;
  $('#add-button').click(function() {
    // One-time initialization
    if (!startedDemo) {
      if (usingSelectorOption()) {
        $('body').popover({
          selector: '.has-popover'
        });
      } else {
        $('.has-popover').popover();
      }

      startedDemo = true;
    }

    // Disable selector checkbox, put a tooltip on it, and show the buttons panel
    $('#use-selector').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#use-selector-label span').tooltip();
    $('.buttons').show();

    // Add a new button that triggers (or doesn't) a popover, with the appropriate message
    var button = null;
    if (usingSelectorOption()) {
      button = $('<button class="btn btn-block btn-success has-popover" data-title="Dynamic" data-content="This button was added dynamically by JavaScript" data-placement="top">Working dynamically added button</button>');
    } else {
      button = $('<button class="btn btn-block btn-default has-popover" data-title="Dynamic" data-content="This button was added dynamically by JavaScript" data-placement="top">Non-working dynamically added button</button>');
    }

    button.appendTo('.buttons');
  });
});
```

But this example does not work when I try to run it. Clicking on the "Add Popover" button has no effect.

There are multiple errors in the console including:

> Blocked loading mixed active content
>
> ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Is there a working example of this feature to be found somewhere?

Comment: Just move the js script tags in head to fix the issue and make the sample running. Here's the updated code https://jsbin.com/focigisitu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I don't know where exactly you found this example, but you are missing the jQuery library ($ is not defined) and popper.js (.popover is not a function). Add those, and you'll be good to go.
Read [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/#overview](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/#overview) for more details.

Comment: The link is in the documentation for selector on the page you just referenced: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/#overview